# Specifying the auxiliary verb before and after the coordinating conjunction

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, verbs, sentence-structure

Are the following two sentences identical?

> It has given me real satisfaction and  motivated me to perform my duties toward mankind.

And

> It has given me real satisfaction and **has** motivated me to perform my duties toward mankind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're *very* close in meaning, but not identical. The use of the [present perfect tense](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html) in `has given` and `has motivated` implies the action *has taken* place once or more in the past in a general sense, but there is no hint of termination.

The use of the [simple past tense](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-past-tense/) (or preterite) in just `motivated` implies the action is completed.

This example might make the distinction more obvious:

> It has *been raining* sporadically this month, but it *rained* heavily yesterday.

In other words, it might still rain some more this month, but yesterday's downpour is done.

Comment: Isn't the second link actually "simple **past** tense"? That is, `The use of the simple past tense (or preterite) in just motivated implies...`

Comment: Your post isn't quite right here, because both clauses are most naturally read as being present perfect. (see @Bailey Parker's answer below)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those two are equivalent in meaning.

Often the second "has" will be inserted to add emphasis, particularly when speaking. Try saying (without breathing):

> It has given me real satisfaction and motivated me to perform my duties.

And then try saying (with emphasis placed on the italicized word and pausing to breathe where indicated):

> It has given me real satisfaction [pause] *and* has motivated me to perform my duties.

If you dropped the second "has" in the latter, it sounds like the speaker has dropped a word.

Also note that you want "towards mankind" not "toward mankind." And, "perform my duties toward mankind" isn't particularly idiomatic. Perhaps try "perform my duties for mankind" or just "serve mankind."

Comment: Thank you so much for additionally correct the phrases "perform my duties...".